# Accessing Single Data from Nested Array JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to access a single data from a JSON file with the url 'https://123.abc.com/student'. I need to display an individual data from this URL. Could someone help me with this?

My Json data looks like this

```
{"students":[{"_id":"5dc516e51bdd2c0014e32e65","name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com","mobile":"9988776655","__v":0},{"_id":"5dc517b51bdd2c0014e32e69","name":"Mark","email":"mark@gmail.com","mobile":"9834783927","__v":0},{"_id":"5dca9231cfba5c0014d3d765","name":"Glen","email":"glen@gmail.com","mobile":"9996474563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb898b9327cb00142169bb","name":"vijay","email":"vijay@gmail.com","mobile":"9884699633","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb89c09327cb00142169bc","name":"tests","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"9887456123","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb8caa9327cb00142169bd","name":"greens","email":"greens@gmail.com","mobile":"9876543210","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb95d69327cb00142169be","name":"Akash","email":"a4akash6@gmail.com","mobile":"9846042118","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb961c9327cb00142169bf","name":"Akash K M","email":"Akash.Madhu@cognizant.com","mobile":"9846042118","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce611ad69f500149660d5","name":"efavewbvwevb","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce874ad69f500149660d6","name":"efavewbvwevb","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce968ad69f500149660d7","name":"indrajit","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing single and array of data

```js
let data = {"students":[{"_id":"5dc516e51bdd2c0014e32e65","name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com","mobile":"9988776655","__v":0},{"_id":"5dc517b51bdd2c0014e32e69","name":"Mark","email":"mark@gmail.com","mobile":"9834783927","__v":0},{"_id":"5dca9231cfba5c0014d3d765","name":"Glen","email":"glen@gmail.com","mobile":"9996474563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb898b9327cb00142169bb","name":"vijay","email":"vijay@gmail.com","mobile":"9884699633","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb89c09327cb00142169bc","name":"tests","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"9887456123","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb8caa9327cb00142169bd","name":"greens","email":"greens@gmail.com","mobile":"9876543210","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb95d69327cb00142169be","name":"Akash","email":"a4akash6@gmail.com","mobile":"9846042118","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb961c9327cb00142169bf","name":"Akash K M","email":"Akash.Madhu@cognizant.com","mobile":"9846042118","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce611ad69f500149660d5","name":"efavewbvwevb","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce874ad69f500149660d6","name":"efavewbvwevb","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce968ad69f500149660d7","name":"indrajit","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0}]}

//access name
console.log('name--', data.students[0].name)

//single object
console.log(data.students[0])

//access array of objects
data.students.map(d=> console.log(d))
```

Comment: Thanks @vahid , could you help me on how to view it as a URL?

Comment: @IndrajitRavi can you explain little more how you want... i didn't get you as URL means what? ...you want to fetch from URL?

Comment: Sorry Im completely new to this. I get the Json data from an url, now if i want to view only one data on the browser say for example 'https://123.abc.com/student/students[0]'

Comment: @IndrajitRavi no bro you can't access like this because it's backend api and for single object you need that api to access... in UI you can access like i posted

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
let data = {"students":[{"_id":"5dc516e51bdd2c0014e32e65","name":"John","email":"john@gmail.com","mobile":"9988776655","__v":0},{"_id":"5dc517b51bdd2c0014e32e69","name":"Mark","email":"mark@gmail.com","mobile":"9834783927","__v":0},{"_id":"5dca9231cfba5c0014d3d765","name":"Glen","email":"glen@gmail.com","mobile":"9996474563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb898b9327cb00142169bb","name":"vijay","email":"vijay@gmail.com","mobile":"9884699633","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb89c09327cb00142169bc","name":"tests","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"9887456123","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb8caa9327cb00142169bd","name":"greens","email":"greens@gmail.com","mobile":"9876543210","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb95d69327cb00142169be","name":"Akash","email":"a4akash6@gmail.com","mobile":"9846042118","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcb961c9327cb00142169bf","name":"Akash K M","email":"Akash.Madhu@cognizant.com","mobile":"9846042118","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce611ad69f500149660d5","name":"efavewbvwevb","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce874ad69f500149660d6","name":"efavewbvwevb","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0},{"_id":"5dcce968ad69f500149660d7","name":"indrajit","email":"indrajitrakurajravi@gmail.com","mobile":"9042758563","__v":0}]}

let result = data.students.forEach(val=>{
  console.log(val)
  // let data individually as 
  let name = val.name 
  let email = val.email 
})
```